# How to iterate / stream a gzip file (containing a single csv)?

Tags: csv, rust, gzip

How to iterate over a gziped file which contains a single text file (csv)?

Searching crates.io I found [flate2](https://crates.io/crates/flate2) which has the following code example for decompression:

```
extern crate flate2;

use std::io::prelude::*;
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;

fn main() {
    let mut d = GzDecoder::new("...".as_bytes()).unwrap();
    let mut s = String::new();
    d.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

How to stream a gzip csv file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For stream io operations rust has the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) and [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) traits.  To iterate over input by lines you usually want the [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait, which you can always get by wrapping a `Read` implementation in [`BufReader::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.new).

`flate2` already operates with these traits; `GzDecoder` implements `Read`, and `GzDecoder::new` takes anything that implements `Read`.

Example decoding stdin (doesn't work well on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9f7a129a0416dacdd59327ce8e133b2a&version=stable) of course):

```
extern crate flate2;

use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let stdin = stdin.lock(); // or just open any normal file

    let d = GzDecoder::new(stdin).expect("couldn't decode gzip stream");

    for line in io::BufReader::new(d).lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

You can then decode your lines with your usual ("without gzip") logic; perhaps make it generic by taking any input implementing `BufRead`.